# How to fix gone dock icons after update to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, unity, icons

After I updated to Ubuntu 20.04 all icons are gone from the dock.

The icons come back a few moments after I open any application, but they never show up right after I log in.

I tried to reset to default gnome settings with this

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

That didn't work. After a restart it did reset the icons but they still only appear after I open an app.

One more thing that might be related is that when I log in I have to select `Ubuntu on Wayland` because with the normal Ubuntu it freezes with a blank screen.

Screenshot:
[image: Desktop screenshot]